# Override forum topics list

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

The forum topics list has this in the table header: Topic, Replies, Created, Last Reply. I just want to remove the Created heading.

Template file [forum-topic-list.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--forum--forum-topic-list.tpl.php/6) prints the table header with `<?php print $header; ?>`

The template file documentation explains that:

> `$header` is pre-generated with click-sorting information. If you need to change this, @see template_preprocess_forum_topic_list() @see theme_forum_topic_list().

So I dig around in forum.module and find [template_preprocess_forum_topic_list()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--forum--forum.module/function/template_preprocess_forum_topic_list/6). This function appears to prepare the variables for the header, but doesn't create the HTML for the output.
I look up the other function that was referenced, `theme_forum_topic_list()`.

The [API documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--theme.php/function/theme_forum_topic_list/6) reports the following:

> This function is never used; see the corresponding template file instead."

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[template_preprocess_forum_topic_list()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--forum--forum.module/function/template_preprocess_forum_topic_list/6) initializes the variable with the value returned from [_theme_table_cell()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/_theme_table_cell/6).

```
global $forum_topic_list_header;

// Create the tablesorting header.
$ts = tablesort_init($forum_topic_list_header);
$header = '';
foreach ($forum_topic_list_header as $cell) {
  $cell = tablesort_header($cell, $forum_topic_list_header, $ts);
  $header .= _theme_table_cell($cell, TRUE);
}
$variables['header'] = $header;
```

```
function _theme_table_cell($cell, $header = FALSE) {
  $attributes = '';

  if (is_array($cell)) {
    $data = isset($cell['data']) ? $cell['data'] : '';
    $header |= isset($cell['header']);
    unset($cell['data']);
    unset($cell['header']);
    $attributes = drupal_attributes($cell);
  }
  else {
    $data = $cell;
  }

  if ($header) {
    $output = "<th$attributes>$data</th>";
  }
  else {
    $output = "<td$attributes>$data</td>";
  }

  return $output;
}
```

The variable `$variables['header']` in `template_preprocess_forum_topic_list()` is the same variable that in forum-topic-list.tpl.php is accessed as `$header`.